# Is it possible to set a view over a modal view?

Tags: ios, swift, modalviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

In this ViewController, it will present a modal view.

After the modal view presented, how to set the following views to over the modal view?

The first view is UIImageView in current ViewController.

The second view is another modal view, in this example, `modalViewController2` will display under the first one.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var img: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidAppear() {
        super.viewDidAppear()

        self.modalViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "modal") as! ModalViewController
        self.modalViewController!.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        self.present(self.modalViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)


        self.modalViewController2 = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "modal2") as! ModalViewController2
        self.modalViewController2!.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        self.present(self.modalViewController2!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First presenting a view controller should be in `viewDidAppear` as in `viewDidLoad` view's hierarchy is not yet complete , second you can't present 2 modal VCs at the same time , better way to make only one modal VC and construct it with say 2 views and manage hide/show for each one according to your need

Comment: Modified the question to `viewDidAppear`, how about the UIImageView?

Comment: instead of adding the VC as modal , you can add it as child VC , and insert the imageView above the View's of that child